# flex-iframe error: This content cannot be displayed in a frame

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, iframe

I have a simple flex application that I created for testing. I download "flex-iframe-1.4.6.zip" library and using this library I am trying to display a url. But it does not show the web page instead it shows an error: "This content cannot be displayed in a frame".

```
<flexiframe:IFrame id="mapIFrame" visible="true" 
    source="http://www.google.com" width="500" height="500" label="Google"/>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you add the parameter `wmode="opaque"` to the embed in your HTML template as described in the [users guide](https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe/wiki/Users-guide)?

Comment: Yes I added it in html template. but it did not make it work.

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: I tried IE9 and Firefox 24.0. it seems as I miss some settings. I googled it a lot and read feedbacks. but nothing works for me.

Comment: Try another URL than google.com. It might depend on the site. The google.com response header contains: `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message *"This content cannot be displayed in a frame"* is coming from Internet Explorer.

See [IE8 Security Part VII: ClickJacking Defenses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/01/27/ie8-security-part-vii-clickjacking-defenses.aspx):

> Web developers can send a HTTP response header named X-FRAME-OPTIONS
>   with HTML pages to restrict how the page may be framed. If the
>   X-FRAME-OPTIONS value contains the token DENY, IE8 will prevent the
>   page from rendering if it will be contained within a frame. If the
>   value contains the token SAMEORIGIN, IE will block rendering only if
>   the origin of the top level-browsing-context is different than the
>   origin of the content containing the X-FRAME-OPTIONS directive.

google.com`s current response header contains: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

So the answer is: you can't use `http://www.google.com` in an iframe.

Accordingly, the example in the [flex-iframe users guide](https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe/wiki/Users-guide) is outdated (last edit 2 years ago).

Comment: when I use Firefox, it does not show this message. Actually it does not show anything, The page remain blank. same is with chrome and safari.

Comment: @SarfrazAhmed The X-Frame-Options response header is respected by all modern browsers. The message "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" is IE specific. Other browsers like Firefox may not show a message, but just a blank iframe.