# ways to open a modal window from asp user control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I am trying to open a popup/ modal window from my asp user control. This popup will be a placeholder for other external websites (ex: Google.com or Facebook.com)

I have tried using iFrame with ModalPopup. But iFrame has issues with many websites and display message 
"this content can not be displayed"

Any pointers?

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="showPop" AlternateText="License Evidence Info" BorderWidth="0px" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../../Images/info.png" OnClientClick="updateObjectIframe(); return false;"/>
<div class="popover-content">
<div id="one" class="popover-content" >
<object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="http://www.google.com" class="popover-content"></object>
</div>
<asp:LinkButton ID="closeLicenseEvidencePop" Text="Close" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Comment: Avoid iframe when possible, they're difficult to control from the "parent" page. You need to post your code showing how you do the popup.

Comment: @mason : trying to attach the code but dont know why that is not getting attached..

Comment: `
<asp:ImageButton ID="showPop" AlternateText="License Evidence Info" BorderWidth="0px" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../../Images/info.png" OnClientClick="updateObjectIframe(); return false;"/>
<div class="popover-content">
<div id="one" class="popover-content" >
<object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="http://www.google.com" class="popover-content"></object>
</div>
<asp:LinkButton ID="closeLicenseEvidencePop" Text="Close" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
`

Comment: Put your code in the question, and show all [relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mason : i realized that iframes is not a good option, so using modal window popup now.. if you can suggest any other solution, then that would be great

Comment: I could make lots of suggestions, but really it comes down to you describing the problem adequately and putting the relevant code in your question. See the link I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

[IFrame: This content cannot be displayed in a frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141388/iframe-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame)

OR

[flex-iframe error: This content cannot be displayed in a frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542221/flex-iframe-error-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame)

I hope ,these are help you.

Comment: that didnt help... still getting This content cannot be displayed error, while using iFrame

Comment: so iFrame can not be used.. since the publisher decides whether a website can be used in a frame.. thats bad!! :(